# Python, call passed function on object

Tags: python

[edit]
Thanks everybody for the help.  This did produce an answer and I have marked the correct answer.

[edit]
I apologize for this hastily formulated question.  I am trying to express what my problem is and the code snippet was written as an abstraction of what I am trying to do.  I have added a new subobject of A and I need to be able to call the anotherFunc on the attribute aThing, as well as A's native functions.

I have a class, A, with function func().  I have an instance of A that is being reinitialized constantly.

```
class B(object):

    def __init__() :
       self.aThing = A()

    def foo(aFunction, args):

      self.aThing = A()
      self.aThing.aFunction(args)

    def bar() :
       self.foo(A.func, anArg)

    def bam()
       self.foo(A.aThing.anotherFunc)

class A(object) :

     def __init__() :
         self.aThing = C()

     def func() :
         doSomething

class C(object):

     def anotherFunc()
        doAnotherThing


x = B()
x.bar()
x.bam()
```

How do I pass the function func so that it is called on the newly initialized object self.aThing?

Comment: You mean to say you want to call `func` only on the newly created `A`?

Comment: Remember to pass the `self` parameter! `def foo(self, ...)`

Comment: Yes only on the newly created A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are probably looking for this:

```
class B(object):

    def foo(self, aFunction, args):
        self.aThing = A("foo")
        aFunction(self.aThing, args)

    def bar(self) :
        self.foo(A.func, ["some", "stuff"])

class A(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def func(self, args) :
        print "func called on", self.name, args

x = B()
x.bar()
```

Note all those `self` parameters, [those are important](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/python-self-explained)! Output:

```
func called on foo ['some', 'stuff']
```

The interesting line is this: `aFunction(self.aThing, args)`. To understand why this works, remember that `aThing.func(args)` is actually the same as `A.func(aThing, args)`.

Comment: Thanks tobias!  This was precisely what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It's not totally clear, but you may want:

```
class B(object):

    def __init__(self): # note 'self' argument
        self.aThing = A()

    def foo(self, aFunction, args): # and here
        self.aThing = A()
        getattr(self.aThing, aFunction)(args)

    def bar(self): # and here
        self.foo("func", anArg) # note string of function name
```

This will call `func` on the new `A` instance, which it accesses using the *name of the function* and [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr). However, note the following caveats:

- As defined, `A.func` doesn't actually have any parameters (again, **including `self`**);
- It is not clear whether the `args` parameter of `B.foo` should be a single argument or a tuple of positional arguments (as it is usually used - `*args`); and
- Where does `anArg` come from?